Pytesseract OCR always fail to recognize the text isinde the image
I have a problem getting the correct text from this image:

I have tried preprocessing the images including morphing, enlarging, greyscaling, and thresholding, but nothing seems to work.
I used OpenCV/NunPy (cv2/numpy modules) too but without success.
This is my script:
from pytesseract import pytesseract
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(file_name)    #, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 
#cv2.dilate(img, (5, 5), img)

img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)


def testOCR(img):

    #print("testOICR():")

    for i in range (14):

        try:
            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config = '--psm %s' % i)

            print("\tOCR psm %s: %s (%s chars) | %s" % (i, repr(text), len(text), text[:-2]))
        except:
            print("\tOCR psm %s failed." % i)


testOCR(img)

And i tried onother one too.. but without success:
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')

# get grayscale image
def get_grayscale(image):
    return cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# noise removal
def remove_noise(image):
    return cv2.medianBlur(image,5)
 
#thresholding
def thresholding(image):
    return cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

#dilation
def dilate(image):
    kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
    return cv2.dilate(image, kernel, iterations = 1)
    
#erosion
def erode(image):
    kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
    return cv2.erode(image, kernel, iterations = 1)

#opening - erosion followed by dilation
def opening(image):
    kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
    return cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

#canny edge detection
def canny(image):
    return cv2.Canny(image, 100, 200)

#skew correction
def deskew(image):
    coords = np.column_stack(np.where(image > 0))
    angle = cv2.minAreaRect(coords)[-1]
     if angle < -45:
        angle = -(90 + angle)
    else:
        angle = -angle
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    center = (w // 2, h // 2)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)
    rotated = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
    return rotated

#template matching
def match_template(image, template):
    return cv2.matchTemplate(image, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)


image = cv2.imread('aurebesh.jpg')

gray = get_grayscale(image)
thresh = thresholding(gray)
opn = opening(gray)
cann = canny(gray)

cv2.imshow('gray', gray)
cv2.imshow('thres', thresh)
cv2.imshow('opening', opn)
cv2.imshow('canny', cann)

cv2.waitKey(0)

Nothing of above scripts work.
Would anyone have any ideas?
PS: I tried using some of the scripts suggested by the community that I found or online, but nothing worked.

How's the output looking like? your image needs no pre-processing in my opinion.

This is the output of the first script:
0 failed.
1: '\x0c' (1 chars) |
2 failed.
3: '\x0c' (1 chars) |
4: '\x0c' (1 chars) |
5: 'C\ny\n0\nYT\n\x0c' (10 chars) | C
y
0
YT
6: '41:-G kn\n\x0c' (10 chars) | 41:-G kn
7: '41:-G kn\n\x0c' (10 chars) | 41:-G kn
8: ' —aeCSkn\n\x0c' (10 chars) |  —aeCSkn
9: '41:-G kn\n\x0c' (10 chars) | 41:-G kn
10: '41:-G kn\n\x0c' (10 chars) | 41:-G kn
11: '41:-G kn\n\x0c' (10 chars) | 41:-G kn
12: '41:-G kn\n\x0c' (10 chars) | 41:-G kn
13: ' —aeCSkn\n\x0c' (10 chars) |  —aeCSkn
The second one show only the altered images.

Try to make the image narrower by resizing. The classic 6 is a G in pytesseract...

Can you post a quickly sample code to achieve this? Thanks

check here the idea is to make the aspect ratio of the numbers more like a normal 4 and 6 (make the imahe narrower)
